# if and return statement

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am new to Android programming, and now I'm working on an application to remind me of the schedule of my lectures. For example, a lecture starts at 12:30 and ends at 1:30 pm. The application will notify me at the date, and turn my phone into the silent mode. My application now works well, but the problem is that after the end of the lecture the app should turn back the phone into Normal mode .
my main_activity Code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ring(12,21,0);
    ring(12,30,1);

}
public void ring (int h,int m,int mode){
/** This intent invokes the activity DemoActivity, which in turn opens the AlertDialog window */
Intent i = new Intent("in.wptrafficanalyzer.servicealarmdemo.demoactivity");
    i.putExtra("mode",mode);

/** Creating a Pending Intent */
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

/** Getting a reference to the System Service ALARM_SERVICE */
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);



int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = h;
int minute = m;

/** Creating a calendar object corresponding to the date and time set by the user */
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);

/** Converting the date and time in to milliseconds elapsed since epoch */
long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

/** Setting an alarm, which invokes the operation at alart_time */
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);

/** Alert is set successfully */
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

my DemoActivity code :

```
public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    /** Creating an Alert Dialog Window */
    AlertDemo alert = new AlertDemo();

    /** Opening the Alert Dialog Window */
    alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "AlertDemo");
}
}
```

my problem is in AlertDemo code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    am = (AudioManager) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    Intent i = this.getActivity().getIntent();
    int info = this.getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("mode", 0);
    if (info == 0) {
        /** Turn Screen On and Unlock the keypad when this alert dialog is displayed */
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        /** Creating a alert dialog builder */
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        /** Setting title for the alert dialog */
        builder.setTitle("Alarm");

        /** Setting the content for the alert dialog */
        builder.setMessage("An Alarm by AlarmManager");
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        final Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getContext(), uri);
        ringtone.play();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            }
        }, 300000);

        /** Defining an OK button event listener */
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                /** Exit application on click OK */
                getActivity().finish();
                ringtone.stop();
            }
        });

        /** Creating the alert dialog window */
        return builder.create();
    }
    else
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
}
```

the problem is missing **return statement** when i add the statement "return null"
This error appears(Application stopped):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.servicealarmdemo/in.wptrafficanalyzer.servicealarmdemo.DemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why would you want to return null there?

Answer (score 0):

In case you return null, your alert object is null. Then you go ahead and ask to perform the "show" method on this object, hence the null pointer exception. Since you do it in the "onCreate" method if DemoActivity, your activity fails to start. Try to make the decision of whether to show the dialog or not beforehand, previously to creating the alert itself. Then just create (and show) the alert only when the mode is suitable (by the way, Java has booleans, why are you using integers?).

Answer (score 0):

Don't do decision making in `onCreateDialog` method. Remove `if-else` block out of `onCreateDialog`

```
public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    am = (AudioManager) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    Intent i = this.getActivity().getIntent();
    int info = this.getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("mode", 0);
    if (info == 0) {
        AlertDemo alert = new AlertDemo();

        /** Opening the Alert Dialog Window */
        alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "AlertDemo");
    } else
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
}
```

}